# Hypergolic Engine Diagram

Tags: engines, hypergolics

Does anyone have any hypergolic rocket engine diagrams, preferably labeled but it's fine if they aren't? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are some in the [Space Shuttle Systems Handbook, Vol II (JSC 11174)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/shuttleultra/files/References/JSC-1117%20-%20Space_Shuttle_Systems_Handbook_Vol2.pdf/download) - Section 11.

Here's an excerpt.

[image]